# USE_ZLIB=1: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I want to compile a simple hello world from Qt console application project, but i get this error:

```
:-1: error: error: USE_ZLIB=1: No such file or directory.
```

My system is Linux Mint 19.1 Cinammon.

I've installed lib64z1 and lib64z1-dev. I used Qt creator's External Library linker manager to link the library directory /usr/lib64. It continously does not work.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it appears to be trying to execute `USE_ZLIB=1` as an external command? Do you now where this string appears in the project?

Comment: No, no idea, im trying out the new alpha release of Qt5.13